# Save word document as PDF with a variable in the filepath?

Tags: vba, file, pdf, ms-word

I'm making a word-macro that saves a word document as PDF, with an array variable in the name, the code as of now looks like this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    'SavePDF
     Dim i As Integer
     i = ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord
     Debug.Print i
     ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 FileName:="C:\temp\PDFSaves\" & finalArray(0, i) & ".pdf"
End Sub
```

But it does not work, any suggestions?

Also, if I set it to save to a filepath that doesn't exist, it will create it right? And I want a **copy** to be saved as  a PDF, not the actual word document since it is a template.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the [ExportAsFixedFormat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Word-VBA/articles/document-exportasfixedformat-method-word).

```
ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:="C:\temp\PDFSaves\" & finalArray(0, i) & ".pdf", ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. Going to check if I can open them now.